# how to set nullable type via reflection code ( c#)?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to set the properties of a class using reflection.

I have a `Dictionary<string,string>` with property names and string values.

Inside a reflection loop, I need to convert the string value to the appropriate property type while setting the value for each property. Some of these property types are nullable types.

1. How can I know from PropertyInfo if the property is a nullable type?
2. How can I set a nullable type using reflection?

**edit:**
The first method defined in the comments on this blog seems to do the trick as well:
http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2006/02/07/437631.aspx

Comment: I doubt you mean "cast" - you can't "cast" a string to an integer, for example. See my answer re conversion.

Comment: you are right - I meant convert - fixed the text!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. One way to do this is:

   ```
   type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)
   ```
2. Just set is as per any other reflection code:

   ```
   propertyInfo.SetValue(yourObject, yourValue);
   ```

Comment: Your "1" will break for non-generic types; "Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null" is safer.

Comment: Or just check type.IsGenericTypeDefinition first

Answer (score 15):

Why do you need to know if it is nullable? And do you mean "reference-type", or "`Nullable<T>`"?

Either way, with string values, the easiest option would be via the `TypeConverter`, which is more-easily (and more accurately) available on `PropertyDescriptor`:

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj);
// then per property...
PropertyDescriptor prop = props[propName];
prop.SetValue(obj, prop.Converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(value));
```

This should use the correct converter, even if set per-property (rather than per-type). Finally, if you are doing lots of this, this allows for acceleration via [`HyperDescriptor`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx), without changing the code (other than to enable it for the type, done once only).

Comment: This works great when matching an object against http form values, where they are all strings to begin with. Thanks.

Comment: @John actually I did some more evil in this area on my blog this week - http://marcgravell.blogspot.com

Answer (score 12):

Specifically to convert an integer to an enum and assign to a nullable enum property:

```
int value = 4;
if(propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType
&& Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) != null
&& Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType).IsEnum)
{
    var enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
    var enumValue = Enum.ToObject(enumType, value);
    propertyInfo.SetValue(item, enumValue, null);

    //-- suggest by valamas
    //propertyInfo.SetValue(item, (value == null ? null : enumValue), null);
}
```

Comment: i suggest `propertyInfo.SetValue(item, (value == null ? null : enumValue), null);` so null can be set, otherwise when setting null, is actually setting the first enum value.

Answer (score 3):

I've created small sample. If you have any questions regarding this code, please add comments.

**EDIT**: updated sample based on great comment by Marc Gravell

```
class Program
{
    public int? NullableProperty { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var value = "123";
        var program = new Program();
        var property = typeof(Program).GetProperty("NullableProperty");

        var propertyDescriptors = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Program));
        var propertyDescriptor = propertyDescriptors.Find("NullableProperty", false);
        var underlyingType =  
            Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyDescriptor.PropertyType);

        if (underlyingType != null)
        {
            var converter = propertyDescriptor.Converter;
            if (converter != null && converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
            {
                var convertedValue = converter.ConvertFrom(value);
                property.SetValue(program, convertedValue, null);
                Console.WriteLine(program.NullableProperty);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nullable.GetUnderlyingType would be easier; also, this won't follow any [TypeConverter(...)] instructions set at the property level, which might (depending on the scenario) be an issue.

Comment: good comment Marc, I agree that GetUnderlyingType would be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, the best solution is mentioned at [MSDN forum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx). However, when you need to implement dynamic solution, where you don't know exactly how many nullable fields may be declared on a class, you best bet is to check if Nullable<> type can be assigned to the 
property, which you inspect via reflection

```
protected T initializeMe<T>(T entity, Value value)
{
  Type eType = entity.GetType();
  foreach (PropertyInfo pi in eType.GetProperties())
        {
            //get  and nsame of the column in DataRow              
            Type valueType = pi.GetType();                
            if (value != System.DBNull.Value )
            {
             pi.SetValue(entity, value, null);
            }
            else if (valueType.IsGenericType && typeof(Nullable<>).IsAssignableFrom(valueType)) //checking if nullable can be assigned to proptety
            {
             pi.SetValue(entity, null, null);
            }
            else
            {
             System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("something here");
            }
            ...
        }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following solution, avoiding use of type converter for taking more control over code.

I wrote a helper class for supporting operations

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Enable using reflection for setting property value 
    /// on every object giving property name and value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="target"></param>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool SetProperty<T>(this T target, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = target.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (pi == null)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false);
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            // Convert the value to set to the properly type
            value = ConvertValue(pi.PropertyType, value);

            // Set the value with the correct type
            pi.SetValue(target, value, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    private static object ConvertValue(Type propertyType, object value)
    {
        // Check each type You need to handle
        // In this way You have control on conversion operation, before assigning value
        if (propertyType == typeof(int) ||
            propertyType == typeof(int?))
        {
            int intValue;
            if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out intValue))
                value = intValue;
        }
        else if (propertyType == typeof(byte) ||
                propertyType == typeof(byte?))
        {
            byte byteValue;
            if (byte.TryParse(value.ToString(), out byteValue))
                value = byteValue;
        }
        else if (propertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            value = value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            // Extend Your own handled types
            Debug.Assert(false);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

**Note: When You set a nullable value (eg. int?, the value need to be almost an integer or castable type. You cannot set int on a byte?. So, You need to convert properly**. See ConvertValue() code, that checks either for type (int) and corresponding nullable type (int?) )

This is code for setting values with the required data structure, Dictionary.

```
    public class Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte? Value { get; set; }
    }

    static void SetNullableWithReflection()
    {
        // Build array as requested
        Dictionary<string, string> props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        props.Add("Name", "First name");
        props.Add("Value", "1");

        // The entity
        Entity entity = new Entity();

        // For each property to assign with a value
        foreach (var item in props)
            entity.SetProperty(item.Key, item.Value);

        // Check result
        Debug.Assert(entity.Name == "First name");
        Debug.Assert(entity.Value == 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for Nullable types is easy, int? is actually `System.Nullable<System.Int32>`.
So you just check if the type is a generic instance of `System.Nullable<T>`.
Setting shouldn't make a difference, `nullableProperty.SetValue(instance, null)` or `nullableProperty.SetValue(instance, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

here is the safest solution for "nullable" object type

```
if (reader[rName] != DBNull.Value)

    {
        PropertyInfo pi = (PropertyInfo)d[rName.ToLower()];
        if (pi.PropertyType.FullName.ToLower().Contains("nullable"))
            pi.SetValue(item, reader[rName]);
        else
            pi.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(reader[rName], Type.GetType(pi.PropertyType.FullName)), null);

    }
```